# Расставить точки в рандомном порядке без пересечений

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, случайные-числа

Требуется зная опорные координаты (например (0,0)) расставить 30 точек вокруг нее, чтобы они стояли как бы хаотично, но не накладывались друг на друга (т.е. чтобы была какая-то минимальная дистанция между ними, например 5). Должно получиться что-то типо этого:

[image: красная - опорная точка]

Если использовать обычный рандом в приделах окружности, то элементы могут накладываться + не известно какого размера окружность выбирать, чтобы все элементы уместились и в то же время окружность не была слишком большой, чтобы точки не были на слишком большом расстоянии. Каким алгоритмом можно получить то, что на картинке?

Comment: так же как Вы проверяете условием, что точка не выходит за пределы окружности, точно также проверяйте условием, что точка не находится рядом с другой. Сохраняйте попутно позиции в массив\объект и при проверке пробегайтесь по нему. Учитывая радиус точки конечно же.

Comment: Подсказывают: при генерации координат точки, записать их в массив. При генерации следующих координат проверить расстояние новых координат со всеми остальными в массиве с помощью формулы расстояния между точками. Если оно меньше  определенной изначально переменной то сгенерировать новые координаты. Также и с общей окружностью

Comment: тут решалась похожа задача с псевдослучайным и равномерным распределением точек - [Генерирование полигональных карт для игр](https://habr.com/post/322504/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Представьте себе спираль, которую вы наматываете от центра.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начните расставлять точки именно таким образом - и вы не будете ломать голову над тем, чтобы подобрать радиус окружности слишком большой или маленький.

В цикле будете складывать в пачку точку за точкой, при этом вам придётся проверять только расположение новой точки относительно старых, а не перебирать заново всю пачку.

Вообще же проблема не такая простая, как вам кажется. Вот почитайте про то, как инженер искал решение подобной задачи: [Проблема Небраски](https://habr.com/post/345346/)